# sending data over serial link with different parities

Tags: serial-port, serial-communication

I am trying to test the difference between no,even and odd parity - always 8 data bits, 1 stop bit

So I have 2 PCs connected with serial cable both running RealTerm or any other terminal.

What I don't understand is that no matter which parity I select on the sending machine the receiver always gets exactly the data I sent. I can change the parity even on the receiver terminal but I always get exactly the same data as sent.

I thought if I send 0x03 with even parity it would show 0x83 on receiver (if set to no parity) and 0x03 (if set to even parity) But this is not happening.

Do I have a misunderstanding regarding parities or what could be the reason?

many thanks!

Comment: If you send a parity bit and the receiver choses to ignore it, then this is what happens.
You could have fun sending with 7bits and parity, receiving 8bits no parity

Comment: whoever downvotet might also like to explain why. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parity bit is the 9th bit, so it will not show up in your data. And it's likely just ignored as in more modern communications there are other means of detecting communications errors and retransmitting (like a CRC check in a block).

The problem is that at the individual byte-level of serial communications there is no means to retransmit in the event of a parity failure, it can only indicate something went wrong.

Comment: The reason I want to sent with odd parity and test it is simply because I am writing a control program for a hardware device I only get in a week or so. I thought I could somehow "simulate" the situation without this device and see if my code works ok. So I guess, this is not possible?

Comment: I guess the question is, what does the device do when it has a parity mismatch? How are you expecting it to respond. But you are right, it's likely not possible.

Comment: I actually don't know yet. OK, I guess I'll have to wait until I get it in my hands. But can a rely on the fact that with a PC it actually will send with even parity + 8 bits when I set it? Or could it be that the PC does not even send/receive the 9th parity bit? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know for certain, but I would expect the PCs to all send what they say they are sending, and the receiver to just ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Only the 8 bits are selected for data, the parity bit is the 9th bit, like in your example you will have :  no parity   0x03 (hex)    0000 0011 (binari)
            even parity 0x103 (hex) 1 0000 0011 (binari) this is what will be send.

If you use realTerm in the "Display As" tab select binary and do not forhet  to set the parity and you will see the parity bit, or use an oscilloscope (if you have), and also on realtTerm there are some flags on  "Status" tab observ them also (BREAK, Error)